# FreeBSD seems doesn't see my dlink wlan at all

Tags: freebsd

I have a PC with a Dlink wireless PCI device in PCI slot. The LEDs are blinking, but when I boot FreeBSD I can not see the device in dmesg.

Why? is it a BIOS issue?

It's pretty ancient hardware. I don't know from where to start dig a problem at least.

```
Copyright (c) 1992-2012 The FreeBSD Project.
Copyright (c) 1979, 1980, 1983, 1986, 1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994
        The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
FreeBSD is a registered trademark of The FreeBSD Foundation.
FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE #0: Tue Jan  3 07:15:25 UTC 2012
    root@obrian.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC i386
module_register: module pci/ral already exists!
Module pci/ral failed to register: 17
CPU: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1.70GHz (1715.31-MHz 686-class CPU)
  Origin = "GenuineIntel"  Id = 0xf13  Family = f  Model = 1  Stepping = 3
  Features=0x3febfbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CLFLUSH,DTS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM>
real memory  = 536870912 (512 MB)
avail memory = 497893376 (474 MB)
Event timer "LAPIC" quality 400
ACPI APIC Table: <ASUS   P4BGL-MX>
ioapic0 <Version 2.0> irqs 0-23 on motherboard
kbd1 at kbdmux0
acpi0: <ASUS P4BGL-MX> on motherboard
acpi0: Overriding SCI from IRQ 9 to IRQ 22
acpi0: Power Button (fixed)
acpi0: reservation of 0, a0000 (3) failed
acpi0: reservation of 100000, 1f700000 (3) failed
Timecounter "ACPI-fast" frequency 3579545 Hz quality 900
acpi_timer0: <24-bit timer at 3.579545MHz> port 0xe408-0xe40b on acpi0
cpu0: <ACPI CPU> on acpi0
acpi_button0: <Power Button> on acpi0
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
vgapci0: <VGA-compatible display> mem 0xe8000000-0xefffffff,0xe7800000-0xe787ffff irq 16 at device 2.0 on pci0
agp0: <Intel 82845M (845M GMCH) SVGA controller> on vgapci0
agp0: aperture size is 128M, detected 8060k stolen memory
uhci0: <Intel 82801DB (ICH4) USB controller USB-A> port 0xd800-0xd81f irq 16 at device 29.0 on pci0
usbus0: <Intel 82801DB (ICH4) USB controller USB-A> on uhci0
uhci1: <Intel 82801DB (ICH4) USB controller USB-B> port 0xd400-0xd41f irq 19 at device 29.1 on pci0
usbus1: <Intel 82801DB (ICH4) USB controller USB-B> on uhci1
uhci2: <Intel 82801DB (ICH4) USB controller USB-C> port 0xd000-0xd01f irq 18 at device 29.2 on pci0
usbus2: <Intel 82801DB (ICH4) USB controller USB-C> on uhci2
ehci0: <Intel 82801DB/L/M (ICH4) USB 2.0 controller> mem 0xe7000000-0xe70003ff at device 29.7 on pci0
usbus3: EHCI version 1.0
usbus3: <Intel 82801DB/L/M (ICH4) USB 2.0 controller> on ehci0
pcib1: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 30.0 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib1
pci2: <base peripheral> at device 9.0 (no driver attached)
pci2: <network, ATM> at device 9.1 (no driver attached)
pci2: <network> at device 10.0 (no driver attached)
rl0: <RealTek 8139 10/100BaseTX> port 0xb800-0xb8ff mem 0xe4800000-0xe48000ff at device 13.0 on pci2
miibus0: <MII bus> on rl0
rlphy0: <RealTek internal media interface> PHY 0 on miibus0
rlphy0:  10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, auto
rl0: Ethernet address: 00:0c:6e:db:3e:09
isab0: <PCI-ISA bridge> at device 31.0 on pci0
isa0: <ISA bus> on isab0
atapci0: <Intel ICH4 UDMA100 controller> port 0x1f0-0x1f7,0x3f6,0x170-0x177,0x376,0xf000-0xf00f irq 18 at device 31.1 on pci0
ata0: <ATA channel 0> on atapci0
ata1: <ATA channel 1> on atapci0
attimer0: <AT timer> port 0x40-0x43 irq 0 on acpi0
Timecounter "i8254" frequency 1193182 Hz quality 0
Event timer "i8254" frequency 1193182 Hz quality 100
atrtc0: <AT realtime clock> port 0x70-0x73 irq 8 on acpi0
Event timer "RTC" frequency 32768 Hz quality 0
ppc0: <Parallel port> port 0x378-0x37f,0x778-0x77b irq 7 drq 3 on acpi0
ppc0: SMC-like chipset (ECP/EPP/PS2/NIBBLE) in COMPATIBLE mode
ppc0: FIFO with 16/16/16 bytes threshold
ppbus0: <Parallel port bus> on ppc0
plip0: <PLIP network interface> on ppbus0
lpt0: <Printer> on ppbus0
lpt0: Interrupt-driven port
ppi0: <Parallel I/O> on ppbus0
uart0: <16550 or compatible> port 0x3f8-0x3ff irq 4 flags 0x10 on acpi0
uart1: <16550 or compatible> port 0x2f8-0x2ff irq 3 on acpi0
atkbdc0: <Keyboard controller (i8042)> port 0x60,0x64 irq 1 on acpi0
atkbd0: <AT Keyboard> irq 1 on atkbdc0
kbd0 at atkbd0
atkbd0: [GIANT-LOCKED]
pmtimer0 on isa0
orm0: <ISA Option ROM> at iomem 0xcc000-0xd0fff pnpid ORM0000 on isa0
sc0: <System console> at flags 0x100 on isa0
sc0: VGA <16 virtual consoles, flags=0x300>
vga0: <Generic ISA VGA> at port 0x3c0-0x3df iomem 0xa0000-0xbffff on isa0
fdc0: No FDOUT register!
p4tcc0: <CPU Frequency Thermal Control> on cpu0
Timecounters tick every 1.000 msec
usbus0: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus1: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus2: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus3: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
ugen0.1: <Intel> at usbus0
uhub0: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus0
ugen1.1: <Intel> at usbus1
uhub1: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus1
ugen2.1: <Intel> at usbus2
uhub2: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus2
ugen3.1: <Intel> at usbus3
uhub3: <Intel EHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 2.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus3
ata1: DMA limited to UDMA33, controller found non-ATA66 cable
ada0 at ata1 bus 0 scbus1 target 1 lun 0
ada0: <SAMSUNG SV2011H RL100-08> ATA-6 device
ada0: 33.300MB/s transfers (UDMA2, PIO 8192bytes)
ada0: 19130MB (39179952 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada0: Previously was known as ad3
Timecounter "TSC" frequency 1715310476 Hz quality 800
Root mount waiting for: usbus3 usbus2 usbus1 usbus0
uhub0: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub1: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub2: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
Root mount waiting for: usbus3
Root mount waiting for: usbus3
uhub3: 6 ports with 6 removable, self powered
Root mount waiting for: usbus3
ugen3.2: <Apple Inc.> at usbus3
Trying to mount root from ufs:/dev/ada0p2 [rw]...
drm0: <Intel i845G GMCH> on vgapci0
info: [drm] AGP at 0xe8000000 128MB
info: [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730
```

pciconf output

```
holms# pciconf -lv
hostb0@pci0:0:0:0:  class=0x060000 card=0x80941043 chip=0x25608086 rev=0x03 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE/PE DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface'
    class      = bridge
    subclass   = HOST-PCI
vgapci0@pci0:0:2:0: class=0x030000 card=0x25621043 chip=0x25628086 rev=0x03 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device'
    class      = display
    subclass   = VGA
uhci0@pci0:0:29:0:  class=0x0c0300 card=0x80891043 chip=0x24c28086 rev=0x02 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller'
    class      = serial bus
    subclass   = USB
uhci1@pci0:0:29:1:  class=0x0c0300 card=0x80891043 chip=0x24c48086 rev=0x02 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller'
    class      = serial bus
    subclass   = USB
uhci2@pci0:0:29:2:  class=0x0c0300 card=0x80891043 chip=0x24c78086 rev=0x02 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller'
    class      = serial bus
    subclass   = USB
ehci0@pci0:0:29:7:  class=0x0c0320 card=0x80891043 chip=0x24cd8086 rev=0x02 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller'
    class      = serial bus
    subclass   = USB
pcib1@pci0:0:30:0:  class=0x060400 card=0x00000000 chip=0x244e8086 rev=0x82 hdr=0x01
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801 PCI Bridge'
    class      = bridge
    subclass   = PCI-PCI
isab0@pci0:0:31:0:  class=0x060100 card=0x00000000 chip=0x24c08086 rev=0x02 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801DB/DBL (ICH4/ICH4-L) LPC Interface Bridge'
    class      = bridge
    subclass   = PCI-ISA
atapci0@pci0:0:31:1:    class=0x01018a card=0x80891043 chip=0x24cb8086 rev=0x02 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801DB (ICH4) IDE Controller'
    class      = mass storage
    subclass   = ATA
none0@pci0:2:9:0:   class=0x088000 card=0x161014f1 chip=0x161014f1 rev=0x01 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Conexant Systems, Inc.'
    device     = 'ADSL AccessRunner PCI Arbitration Device'
    class      = base peripheral
none1@pci0:2:9:1:   class=0x020300 card=0x161114f1 chip=0x161114f1 rev=0x01 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Conexant Systems, Inc.'
    device     = 'AccessRunner PCI ADSL Interface Device'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ATM
rl0@pci0:2:13:0:    class=0x020000 card=0x80b31043 chip=0x813910ec rev=0x10 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.'
    device     = 'RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
```

Here is photo of device.. if you need any chipset id's. 
[image: dlink wifi pci card]

Comment: Do you have any unknown devices on the PCI bus if you run `lspci`?

Comment: there's no lspci on freebsd.. correct me if I wrong.. I added dmesg dump

Comment: On a FreeBSD 7 server: `which lspci` -> `/usr/local/bin/lspci`.  But on A freshly installed FreeBSD 9.1 there is indeed no such command, but there is /usr/sbin/pciconf   As for the dmesg., I notice a "pci2: <network> at device 10.0 (no driver attached)".

Comment: can you post the output of pciconf -lv for this pci2 device? Also you can try to find out, what chipset the card is using.

Comment: Ok i changed question, because we actually starting to dig into device it self. In result i'd like to load this dlink wlan card.. i've found some guides for this model, but they all assume that after loading driver i'll have `ral0` device in `ifconfig` although it's doesnt appear in there.

Comment: The interesting thing is, there is no Dlink card in your pciconf output, only an ADSL card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kldload if_ral` or other appropriate if_* kernel module